# Regex to match any Javascript/jQuery function declaration line

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, editor, prototypejs

I have following regex pattern for matching any function declaration of type `function funcname() {`.

```
function\s+(.*?)\)\s*{
```

But sometimes in Javascript/jQuery functions are declared in below ways too:

`funcName = function() {`

Or

`jQuery.fn.funcName = function () {`

I don't know how to ORify regex to allow all the above syntaxes to be matched. Braces maybe in nextline acording to code format rules.

Comment: Use [`(?:(\w+(?:\.\w+)*)\s*=\s*)?function\s*(.*?)\(`](https://regex101.com/r/lO0cB9/1) and check if Group 2: if it matched, use it, if not, use Group 1 value.

Comment: Thanks, this works for me too, please don't remove this comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
function.*{|\w* \= function.*{|jquery.*{
```

The vertical bar character is how you "orify" in regex.

And to deal with multiple lines you need to use the newline selector: \n

For example, to match:

```
function funcname() {

}
```

You might use:

```
function.*\{\n*}
```

Comment: This is the shortest regex matching all the function syntaxes in Javascript and jQuery. Thanks a lot.

Comment: One more thing, please provide a break up of your regex and can you enclose this in brackets to make a group such that if I want to add something just after this declaration line including a newline char ?

Comment: @VickyDev I don't understand, please clarify

Comment: Explain your regex step wise means character wise(regex characters) and how to enclose this whole regex into bracket and add some string along with newline char just after this ?